# Return Method local_variables as Hash

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I'm generating some local variables in a method.  I would like to find a way of returning them in a hash with keys and values, but the generation of that very hash ends up in the return itself.  How can I avoid this?

```
def get_map_libs()
  libjq = JSON.parse(File.read(URI.open('https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery', 'r')))['latest']
  liblf = JSON.parse(File.read(URI.open('https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries/leaflet', 'r')))['latest']
  libbs = JSON.parse(File.read(URI.open('https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap', 'r')))['latest']
  libfa = JSON.parse(File.read(URI.open('https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome', 'r')))['latest']
  return {libjq: libjq, liblf: liblf, libbs: libbs, libfa: libfa}
#   return local_variables
end
```

This method works as expected.  There should be a way of grabbing `local_variables` and returning it.  However, when I use that commented-out return (`return local_variables`), it only returns their keys:

```
[
    [0] :libjq,
    [1] :liblf,
    [2] :libbs,
    [3] :libfa
]
```

I tried building a return hash `r = {}` and populating it, however that very hash also shows up in the return.  I tried deleting it, but that throws an error when I try to delete itself in itself.

Can this be done or do I have to hard code it like above?

Comment: Side note: if you post examples on Stack Overflow, make sure they are as minimal and self-contained as possible. There is nothing in your question about local variables that requires Internet access, yet the example you posted makes it impossible to copy&paste and test it e.g. on an airplane. (Granted, in the current situation, I spend much less time in planes than I used to … but still.)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`local_variables`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-local_variables) tells that it only returns an array with the names of the local variables.

But you could use that method to generate the hash:

```
local_variables.map { |name| [name, eval(name.to_s)] }.to_h
```

I think that is a bit error-prone because you might return unexpected variables and their values.

Perhaps it would be better to refector your method to something like this:

```
LIBRARIES = { 
  libjq: 'jquery',
  liblf: 'leaflet',
  libbs: 'twitter-bootstrap',
  libfa: 'font-awesome'
}

def library_urls
  LIBRARIES.map { |k, v| 
    [k, JSON.parse(URI.open("https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries/#{v}").read)['latest']] 
  }.to_h  
end
```

Comment: Your first snippet assumes that there is method with the same name as the local variable for every single local variable in scope. That seems highly unlikely and there is nothing in the original question that indicates that is the case. And even if it were, the OP clearly wants to return the values of the local variables, not the return value of a method that happens to have the same name as the local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that you are assigning the result hash to a local variable, so if you want to return a list of local variables, then of course that variable will be included.

The two simplest solutions I can think of would be:

Filter out the name of that local variable.

Just don't assign it. I.e. where you have `r = something`, just return `something` without assigning it to `r` in the first place. Something like this:

```rb
def get_map_libs
  libjq = :jq
  liblf = :lf
  libbs = :bs
  libfa = :fa

  local_variables.map {|var| [var, binding.local_variable_get(var)] }.to_h
end

get_map_libs
#=> { :libjq => :jq, :liblf => :lf, :libbs => :bs, :libfa => :fa }
```

Comment: I was trying something along those lines, but you took it back to the hash I was looking for.